# Pop-up window to confirm

Tags: javascript, popup

Where should i fit in a pop-up, using this existing piece of code?

```
<td>
  <input type="button" value="Save" name="btnFormAction"
         onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={https://abc-public.sharepoint.com}')}" />
</td>
```

I want a pop-up to confirm that "your stuff is saved" Before redirecting back to the start page. 
Thanks
Sanna

Answer (score 1):

Write the below code in a script editor webpart:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

         function PostSaveAction(){ 
              alert("Your item is created!!");
              window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";         
              return true;  
             }  
    </script>
```

This function is called after an item is created.

Comment: Can I use this with current code that is used for redirecting onclick event?

Comment: just call a function like the one which i mentioned in my previous answer. See edit history

Answer (score 0):

Define a click function on the save button and do something like this

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   //execute operations for saving data
   alert("Changes Saved");
   //redirect the user
});
```

The alert function halts execution of the code until it's dismissed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get this to work. I have too little experience to know exactely how to fit this in and there were many errors trying this.

Comment: You might have missed jQuery's reference as far as the errors are concerned and you can add the above code in Content Editor WebPart.